# Rows not copied to destination table from source table using oracle sqlplus copy command

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am using this copy command.

```
COPY FROM username/[pwd]@identifier INSERT SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME 
USING SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
```

Note : Both the source and target tables are in different databases. The source table has around 19 million records. Both tables have 198 columns.

and I am getting the below message when the copy command is executed (I am not seeing any error message but no rows are copied).

```
Array fetch/bind size is 5000. (arraysize is 5000)

Will commit after every 100 array binds. (copycommit is 100)

Maximum long size is 80. (long is 80)

   0 rows selected from username/[pwd]@identifier.

   0 rows inserted into SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME.

   0 rows committed into SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME at DEFAULT HOST connection.
```

Please help me on this or any possible guidance to tackle above issue is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on my local 11g XE database; it works OK.

```
SQL> create table test as select * From dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> copy from scott/tiger@xe insert test using select * from dept;

Array fetch/bind size is 15. (arraysize is 15)
Will commit when done. (copycommit is 0)
Maximum long size is 80. (long is 80)
   4 rows selected from scott@xe.
   4 rows inserted into TEST.
   4 rows committed into TEST at DEFAULT HOST connection.

SQL> select * From test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

Your query selected *nothing* and inserted *nothing*, which looks as if query doesn't do what you thought it would. Did you make sure that it is correctly written and that it fetches some rows?

---

As of *disadvantages*: [Oracle 19c documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-COPY-command.html#GUID-3565689A-6B8C-42FB-95F3-0412C707377E) says that

> The COPY command will be deprecated in future releases of SQL*Plus. After Oracle 9i, no new datatypes are supported by COPY.

so you'd probably rather use other options to *move* data around. That would be e.g.

- `INSERT INTO`
- `MERGE`
- data pump export & import

Comment: Thanks a ton sir.

Comment: Sir could you please  suggest the disadvantages of copy command.

Comment: You're welcome. As of disadvantages, I added some more info into the answer. Have a look, please.